# standalone + xelatex + koma-script?

Tags: xetex, koma-script, standalone

a page is not cropped, when `standalone` class is used together with `xelatex` and koma-script classes (`scrreprt`,`scrbook` or `scrartcl`). Here is very short MWE:

```
\documentclass[class=scrreprt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    text
\end{document}
```

and it works just fine when instead compiled with `pdflatex` or with standard classes (i.e. replacing `scrreprt` in MWE by `article`, `book` etc). is there a chance to get a cropped page with `standalone+xelatex+koma-script` working together? (I use latest versions of the packages)

Comment: How do expect to use two classes within the same document?

Comment: the class is actually standalone, but there is also the possibility to specify the underlying class as shown in MWE.

Comment: Didn't know that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
\documentclass[class=scrreprt,preview]{standalone}
```

Answer (score 6):

Deactivate KOMA-Script option `pagesize` (default is `auto`):

```
\documentclass[class=scrreprt,pagesize=off]{standalone}
\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, I confirm that it also solves my issue!